# A desktop environment with mnemonics for Debian 8?

Tags: desktop-environment, user-interface, gtk3

Mnemonics - the underlined letters in menus and buttons, controlled by the option `gtk-enable-mnemonics` - have been deprecated in GTK3, and indeed they are not available in my GNOME Shell 3.14.4.  Since I avoid the mouse as much as possible, I miss them.  I know that by pressing `Alt`, mnemonics are shown, but that is not the same because, besides the obvious delay, I may have to switch hands to press the keyboard shortcut ergonomically. Is there a desktop environment for Debian 8 that still has mnemonics?